# Install Landscape dedicated server

Tags: apt, landscape

I am having an issue to install landscape on prem.  I receive the following message:

```
sudo apt-get install landscape-server
```

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package landscape-server
```

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landscape/16.03
```

```
 LDS 16.03
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~landscape/+archive/ubuntu/16.03
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpc36elht0/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpc36elht0/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 4652B4E6 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpc36elht0/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 4652B4E6: public key "Launchpad PPA for Landscape" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

```
sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
```

```
sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
```

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package landscape-server-quickstart
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using 16.04?

> OPL 16.03 supports Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ("trusty"). It can only be upgraded from OPL 15.11. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ("xenial") is NOT supported by OPL 16.03.